# React Flux Uncaught TypeError: _LocalityStore2.default.setSelectedLocality is not a function

Tags: javascript, flux, reactjs-flux

I have HomeLayout from where I get redirected to MobileLocalityLayout which has a method selectLocality to set locality value to LocalityStore on clicking a link called "set locality". Now as soon as I select locality I am redirected to the HomeLayout and after that if press locality button again and select locality, I get following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: _LocalityStore2.default.setSelectedLocality is not a function
```

However LocalityStore has the function `setSelectedLocality`.

**Code Snippets:**

HomeLayout :

```
<span class='selectLocalityBtn'><Link to="/selectLocality">Set Locality</Link></span>
```

MobileLocalityLayout:

```
selectLocality(val){
        this.setState({
            selectedLocality : val
        });
        LocalityStore.setSelectedLocality(val);
        browserHistory.push("/");
    }
```

LocalityStore:

```
setSelectedLocality(locality){
    this.setSelectedLocality = locality;
}
```

Am I implementing flux in wrong way. I don't understand what is `_LocalityStore2` as I have LocalityStore and not LocalityStore2. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your code

```
setSelectedLocality(locality){
    this.setSelectedLocality = locality;
}
```

please replace this.setSelectedLocality with this.selectedLocality

Answer (score 0):

It looks (by the name convention) like you are calling setSelectedLocality on a class and not instance. While exporting LocalityStore create an instance of it and then call methods on it. Like this:

```
const localityStore = new LocalityStore();
dispatcher.register(localityStore.handler.bind(localityStore));
export default localityStore;
```

About this name change (LocalityStore to _LocalityStore2). I guess you are using `babel-react-loader` or something like this to transpile your code to ES5. This causes some changes to the original code, but it's not a problem.

Comment: Yes I am using babel transpiler